# matplotlib + PyQt5: How to transfer parameters?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

To this question I am referring to the code from:
 http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/matplotlib/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html

I made some modifications to the code. I would like to ask how to transfer parameters from `class ApplicationWindow` into `class MyStaticMplCanvas`.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import os
import random
import matplotlib
# Make sure that we are using QT5
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

progname = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
progversion = "0.1"


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

    def compute_initial_figure(self, input_List):
        print(input_List)
        t = arange(input_List[0], 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("application main window")

        self.file_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&File', self)
        self.file_menu.addAction('&Quit', self.fileQuit,
                                 QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.Key_Q)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.file_menu)

        self.help_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&Help', self)
        self.menuBar().addSeparator()
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.help_menu)

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        input_List = [0, 1, 2]  # How to transfer this input_List into MyStaticMplCanvas?
        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100, input_List)
        l.addWidget(sc)

        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("All hail matplotlib!", 2000)

    def fileQuit(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, ce):
        self.fileQuit()


qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

aw = ApplicationWindow()
aw.setWindowTitle("%s" % progname)
aw.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `compute_initial_figure` method directly through the `sc` object:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    """Simple canvas with a sine plot."""

    def compute_initial_figure(self, input_List):
        print(input_List)
        t = arange(input_List[0], 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("application main window")

        self.file_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&File', self)
        self.file_menu.addAction('&Quit', self.fileQuit,
                                 QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.Key_Q)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.file_menu)

        self.help_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&Help', self)
        self.menuBar().addSeparator()
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.help_menu)

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        input_List = [0, 1, 2]  # How to transfer this input_List into MyStaticMplCanvas?
        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        sc = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        l.addWidget(sc)
        sc.compute_initial_figure(input_List)

        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage("All hail matplotlib!", 2000)

    def fileQuit(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, ce):
        self.fileQuit()
```

**Note:** *I recommend reading about OOP.*

Comment: I found matplotlib is much more difficult to learn than PyQt, because it is very 'scattered'. It looks like a different language for me.

Comment: @LucasMeier matplotlib is much more "python" than pyqt, it looks like the standard python libraries.

Comment: @LucasMeier The most likely thing that happens in your case is that you have not secured the knowledge of basic programming, neither of Python, nor of OOP.

Comment: That is true. I have been trying to use python for almost two years, but am still a newbie. :-(